# construct vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, size-type

I am currently working on implementing the constructor function for the vector class(my professor said that we can leave out anything that uses an allocator).  I used the reference website that my professor gave us to determine the format of the function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/

I am getting some errors in my function.  Two of the errors are:

syntax error: identifier 'size_type'

'value' : undeclared identifier

Any idea why I would be getting these errors?  Here is my code:

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const T& value= T())
{
    my_vect=new int x[2*n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        vect[i]=value;
        length++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling this code? what system are you on windows or linux? what compiler are you using? did you include the correct libraries? these are all questions that must be answered

Comment: I have the same issue compiling under Microsoft Visual Studio. Replace the size_type with size_t, and it compiles fine. Size_t seems to be more commonly used anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your class in an .h file, then the `= T()` is the default value. When you implement the method in the .cpp or .cc file, you leave out the default value.

size_type is not in global scope it seems, so you need to use the resolution operator to give it correct scope. It appears to be `std::string::size_type`. This is probably just a typedef for `size_t`. I see size_type in the STL containers, but I've never used it when creating my own classes.

Also, as Dietmar Kühl mentioned, when using C++ templates, you need to decorate everything with `template <typename T>`

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is lacking quite a bit of context. This makes it hard to tell where the problem is. From the error message it seems that you at the very least haven't defined `size_type`. It also looks as if `T` isn't defined which makes me think you try to define the constructor out of line but this would look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T>::vector(size_type n, T const& value):
    my_vect(new T[2u * n]),
    length(n)
{
    for (size_type i(0); i != n; ++i) {
        my_vect[i] = value;
    }
   // or: std::fill_n(my_vect, n, value);
}
```

This also fixed a few errors (use of `int` vs. `T`, `vect` vs. `my_vext`, uninitialized use of `length`). Note that the idiomatic way to increment variable in C++ is to use preincrement (yes, the language should actually be called "++C" for more reasons than just the idiomatic use).

Comment: Just wanted to point out: "size_type" is one of many expected types for STL containers.  It's usually just a typedef for size_t.  The full list of them is on the link that Katelyn Sapio mentioned earlier: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/